# Как сохранять старую цену при парсинге криптобиржи?

Tags: python, парсер

Например я спарсил цену, проходит время, я снова вызываю функцию (новая цена перезаписывает старую), а мне нужно сравнять с прошлой ценой (прошлой цены уже нету). Как мне сохранить старую цену?

Как я сейчас парсю цену:

```
def get_ticker(coin1="btc", coin2="usd"):
    response = requests.get(url=f"https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/{coin1}_{coin2}?ignore_invalid=1")

    return response.text

def get_avg(coin="btc"):
    resp = get_ticker(coin)
    as_dict = loads(resp)
    avg = as_dict[f'{coin}_usd']['avg']

    return str(float('{:.2f}'.format(avg))) + "$"
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сохраняйте результат

Comment: Создай базу данных, тот же SQLite, записывай в таблицу данные при парсинге, а данные потом крути-верти как хочешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохрани в json
или в csv
или в txt
или в любой другой файл

Comment: Спс, так и сделал на некст день